What killed my process? No relevant entries seen via dmesg or journalctl on Rocky Linux 9.2 (Blue Onyx)
A program from a vendor gets killed instantly. I need to know why. Log shows nothing relevant. Any advice? I looked into OOM killer etc. Added tons of swap. Did not specify log in journalctl so I presume it shows all.
[sbvirapp1039@sbvirapp1039 hl7Proxy]$ date
Fri Apr 12 02:38:17 PM EDT 2024
[sbvirapp1039@sbvirapp1039 hl7Proxy]$ ./hl7Proxy-Radiology/hl7proxy-linux-amd64 -port 13133 -config Radiology-hl7v2-entry -url http://sbvirapp.sw.ca/ -header "Authorization: Basic XXXXXXXXXXX="
2024/04/12 14:38:21 INFO: Listening to :13133
Killed
[sbvirapp1039@sbvirapp1039 hl7Proxy]$ sudo journalctl --since="2024-04-12 14:32:00" --utc --no-pager 
Apr 12 18:35:36 sbvirapp1039.sw.ca sudo[93042]: sbvirapp1039 : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/home/sbvirapp1039/hl7Proxy ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/bin/journalctl --since=2024-04-12 14:26:00 --utc --no-pager
Apr 12 18:35:36 sbvirapp1039.sw.ca sudo[93042]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root(uid=0) by sbvirapp1039(uid=1000)
Apr 12 18:35:36 sbvirapp1039.sw.ca sudo[93042]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
Apr 12 18:35:48 sbvirapp1039.sw.ca sudo[93049]: sbvirapp1039 : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/home/sbvirapp1039/hl7Proxy ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/bin/dmesg -H
Apr 12 18:35:48 sbvirapp1039.sw.ca sudo[93049]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root(uid=0) by sbvirapp1039(uid=1000)
Apr 12 18:35:48 sbvirapp1039.sw.ca sudo[93049]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
Apr 12 18:38:12 sbvirapp1039.sw.ca sudo[93058]: sbvirapp1039 : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/home/sbvirapp1039/hl7Proxy ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/bin/dmesg -H
Apr 12 18:38:12 sbvirapp1039.sw.ca sudo[93058]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root(uid=0) by sbvirapp1039(uid=1000)
Apr 12 18:38:12 sbvirapp1039.sw.ca sudo[93058]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
Apr 12 18:38:35 sbvirapp1039.sw.ca sudo[93067]: sbvirapp1039 : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/home/sbvirapp1039/hl7Proxy ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/bin/journalctl --since=2024-04-12 14:32:00 --utc --no-pager
Apr 12 18:38:35 sbvirapp1039.sw.ca sudo[93067]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root(uid=0) by sbvirapp1039(uid=1000)
[sbvirapp1039@sbvirapp1039 hl7Proxy]$ sudo dmesg -H | tail
[  +0.474806] br-3905e73e31dd: port 2(vethb53d12d) entered disabled state
[  +0.056531] eth0: renamed from veth91cb8ab
[  +0.001097] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): vethb53d12d: link becomes ready
[  +0.000042] br-3905e73e31dd: port 2(vethb53d12d) entered blocking state
[  +0.000003] br-3905e73e31dd: port 2(vethb53d12d) entered forwarding state
[Apr 9 18:21] Loading of module with unavailable key is rejected
[  +0.001955] Loading of module with unavailable key is rejected
[Apr12 11:56] traps: normand[57594] trap divide error ip:40111c sp:7fff952ac2a0 error:0 in normand[401000+1000]
[Apr12 12:00] traps: normand[57698] trap divide error ip:40111c sp:7ffdb92df980 error:0 in normand[401000+1000]
[Apr12 12:43] Adding 19999996k swap on /home/swapfile.  Priority:-3 extents:4 across:206315096k SSFS
[sbvirapp1039@sbvirapp1039 hl7Proxy]$ 


Sanitized strace output, last lines are:
93198 setsockopt(3, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, [1], 4) = 0
93198 bind(3, {sa_family=AF_INET6, sin6_port=htons(13133), sin6_flowinfo=htonl(0), inet_pton(AF_INET6, "::", &sin6_addr), sin6_scope_id=0}, 28) = 0
93198 listen(3, 4096)                   = 0
93198 epoll_ctl(5, EPOLL_CTL_ADD, 3, {events=EPOLLIN|EPOLLOUT|EPOLLRDHUP|EPOLLET, data={u32=877527000, u64=140364703727576}}) = 0
93198 getsockname(3, {sa_family=AF_INET6, sin6_port=htons(13133), sin6_flowinfo=htonl(0), inet_pton(AF_INET6, "::", &sin6_addr), sin6_scope_id=0}, [112 => 28]) = 0
93198 openat(AT_FDCWD, "/etc/localtime", O_RDONLY) = 4
93198 read(4, "TZif2\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\6\0\0\0\6\0\0\0\0"..., 4096) = 3552
93198 read(4, "", 4096)                 = 0
93198 close(4)                          = 0
93198 write(2, "2024/04/12 15:11:19 INFO: Listen"..., 46) = 46
93198 accept4(3, 0xc00004dbd8, [112], SOCK_CLOEXEC|SOCK_NONBLOCK) = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
93198 epoll_pwait(5, [], 128, 0, NULL, 0) = 0
93198 epoll_pwait(5,  <unfinished ...>
93199 <... nanosleep resumed>NULL)      = 0
93199 futex(0x8d0fa0, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 0, {tv_sec=60, tv_nsec=0} <unfinished ...>
93201 futex(0xc000040948, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 0, NULL <unfinished ...>
93198 <... epoll_pwait resumed> <unfinished ...>) = ?
93200 <... futex resumed>)              = ?
93200 +++ killed by SIGKILL +++
93199 <... futex resumed>)              = ?
93199 +++ killed by SIGKILL +++
93201 <... futex resumed>)              = ?
93201 +++ killed by SIGKILL +++
93198 +++ killed by SIGKILL +++



Impossible to say w/ the info provided. I'd suggest capturing stderr to a file and running the whole thing under strace for a while ...  strace -vf -o ~/strace.out ./hl7Proxy-Radiology/hl7proxy-linux-amd64 -port 13133 -config Radiology-hl7v2-entry -url http://sbvirapp.sw.ca/ -header "Authorization: Basic XXXXXXXXXXX=" 2>>~/debugging

20 gb of swap isn't all that much.  Disable memory overcommit and see what process errors out.

@NormandRobert Please edit your question and add the new information there. It makes it much easier to track what is going on and is more searchable.

OK added links to strace output in question and also here:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1tl6TZEsVkzQL6ekOI8f81gN9KpMdcOV8/view?usp=drive_link

@NormandRobert you may want to remove your credentials from the strace output (and change them on the remote end). I didn't ask you to post that here.

@NormandRobert - at this point (assuming that there was nothing of help/interest in the debugging file) I'd contact their support, mentioned at the bottom of their github page ...

Indeed aidbox provided that utility and I have provided them with the trace. Thank you all.
